# Best way to prevent repeat results?

Tags: database, string, performance, list

I have a list of quotes and I need to pull random quotes from the list. I want to create a bias against getting repeat quotes (the quotes can be repeated but I want to bias against a repeat if possible). Pretty much I just want the user to not feel like the quotes are repeating. What's the most efficient way to accomplish this?

My current idea is to pull x amount of quotes from the list initially, preventing repeats. Then when I have to pull x more quotes then I save the last quote that was used then make sure the next set of quotes doesn't have the last one (so that there isn't a repeat of quotes from the last quote).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the entire list from the database, then have the serverside language (eg php, .net, etc) shuffle the array. Then use from row 0 to say row 9. The next time use rows 10-19